# Combine queries in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I am working on a running tracker app for Android phones. For this I will make a follower part also and a news feed.

My question is, is there any possibility the combine queries?
First I have to check the followed people by the currently logged in user, after that I have to check the time of their last training and order it by descending.

So what I need is a list about the followed people what is ordered by their last training.

Can I do it with one combined query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent of a SQL join, if that's what you're asking. You can only express one query at a time.  You can kick them off in parallel, but you have to handle their results individually.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking. Thanks :)